# Create a json file from an array with php, return it and use it with javascript from a javascript file in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, wordpress

Here's my problem: I created a json file with php and I need to access it with javascript (ajax?) in order to print some result on my map.

For me it's very hard, but I'm giving a try step by step.

Here's the first step:

```
function phptojson($prog = null , $prov = null, $slang = null , $fees = null) {

    $posts = getData(null , null, null, null);
    $data = [];

    foreach($posts as $post) {

        $data[$post->ID] = [
            "program_type" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'program_type', true ),
            "province" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'province', true ),
            "language" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'language_of_study', true ),
            "tuition" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tuition_fees', true ),
            "lenght" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'length_of_study', true ),
            "title" => $post->post_title,
            "location" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'location', true ),
            "information" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'details', true ),
        ];

    }
    return json_encode($data);

}
```

getData is a function that will call some parameter in order to filter my query, and return data from the database that I need. The second step is the loop, which is working fine, and finally I return my json file.

Now my trouble, which is: what could I do with this file. The older code that I'm improving was using a script tag in order to print the file on the HTML document to access it.

I want to call my funtion phptojson from my javascript file in order to access it. I've aready created the google maps, which is working fine, so I only need to print the result from my javascript function. My file hierarcy looks like that:

wp-content
  -themes
    -mytheme
     myfunction.php (where I put phptojson() )
       -js
          myscript.js

Essentially I want to call my function from myscript.js with ajax and I'm trying this approach that I found here, but it's not working:

```
function getJsonElement() {
    $.get('/includes/custom-function.php', function(phptojson) {      
    console.log(data);
} );
}
```

Which kind of makes sense.. What could it be my next step?

PS. My json file looks like:

```
string(162036) "{"1439":
{"program_type":"long","province":"NY","language":"EN","tuition":"10","lenght":"full","title":"My School","location":"10 awesome street, NY, US"}}
```

Comment: yes, it's a WordPress environment

Comment: WordPress has a framework for doing AJAX requests you should use it instead of writing your own AJAX handlers. The documentation is with their plugin documentation. I can find its URL if you cannot locate it but I am to lazy and too busy right now.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate

Comment: I suggest you change your data structure to a standard array.  The current output will give you a javascript object with numbered properties.  In order to use any of the standard array techniques in javascript for filtering, sorting, mapping, iterating, etc, you will need to convert your object each time to a standard array.  So save time by doing that up front.  You might want to include the id as a property of each row.